# Get object values in loop by the property name c#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

Everyone hello,
What I need in the project is to insert into a database but there are 195 columns in the database, so I want to enter stored procedure parameters with object and class logic on c # side to make this work easier.

I've easily gotten the property names of the class I created for the database sorts, but I'm having a hard time filling in their values.

Class

```
 public class StokItem
    {
            public int prop1 { get; set; }
            public short prop2 { get; set; }
            public int prop3 { get; set; }
            .....
 }
```

Program Codes

```
String [] propNamestypeof = typeOf (StokItem) .GetProperties (). Select (p => p.Name) .ToArray ();

StokItem item = new StokItem ();
Item.prop1 = blablabla
Item.prop2 = asddsad;
...
.
.

 For (int i = 0; i <195; i ++) {
     ScCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@" + propNamestypeof [i], XXXXX);
       }
```

Meaning XXXX; The value of the attribute in the index i is the value of the obgen (I am filling it before)

What I mean is how can I do this for a table with so many fields item.propNamestypeOf [i] actually want to do it, but does not it accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code might be helps you

```
StokItem item = new StokItem();
item.prop1 = 123;
item.prop2 = 456;
...

foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    //string propertyName = prop.Name;
    //var propertyValue = prop.GetValue(item);
    ScCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@" + prop.Name, prop.GetValue(item));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for what I'm looking for!